# Understanding PNG file format IDAT segment

Tags: c++, parsing, graphics, png

From the sample image below, I have a border in yellow just for display purposes only.

The actual .png file is a simple black/white image 3 pixels by 3 pixels.  I was originally thinking to try as a 2x2, but that would not help trying to interpret low/hi vs hi/low drawing stream.  At least this way, I would have two black, one white from the top, or one white, two black from the bottom..

So I read the chunks of data, get to the IDAT chunk, decode that (zlib) and come up with 12 bytes as follows

00 20 00 40 00 80

So, my question, how does the above get broken down into the 3x3 black and white sample...  Also, it is saved in palette format and properly recognizes the bit depth of 1 and color palette of 2... color pallet[0] is RGBA all zeros.  Palette[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceEjG.png) has RGBA of 255, 255, 255, 0

I'll eventually get into the multiple other depth formats later, just wanted to start with what would expect to be the easiest.

Part II.  Any guidance on handling the other depth formats would help if anything special to be considered especially regarding alpha channel (which I am already looking for in the palette) that might trip me up.

[image]

Comment: If you want to fully understand the IDAT format, just read the standard, it's quite simple: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#11IDAT

Comment: Thanks for that additional document... I'll look into that too, but the one below actually cleared up a BUNCH for me that I did not actually follow from any spec...  Graphics is not my primary, so I'm trying to learn vs just "here... use this."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It wouuld be easier if you use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), so I guess this is for learning purposes.

The thing is if you decompress the IDAT chunk directly, you get some data that is not supposed to be displayed and/or may need to be *transformed* (because a filter was applied) to get the actual bytes. In PNG format each line starts with an extra byte that tells you which filter was applied to that line, the remaining bytes contain the line pixels.

BTW, `00 20 00 40 00 80` are 6 bytes only (not 12, as you think). Now if you see this data as binary, your 3 lines would look like this:

> 00000000  00100000
>   00000000  01000000
>   00000000  10000000

Now, your image is 1 bit per pixel, so 1 byte is required to save a line of 3 pixels. The 3 highest bits are actually used (the 5 lower bits are ignored). I replaced the ignored bits with a `x`, so I think is easier to see the actual *pixels* (`0` is black, `1` is white):

> 00000000  001xxxxx
>   00000000  010xxxxx
>   00000000  100xxxxx

In this case, no filter was applied to any line, because the first byte of each line is zero (`0` means no filter applied, values from `1` to `4` means a filter was applied).

Comment: Reading the canonical file format on [libpng](http://www.libpng.org) is a *must*. Other bit depths are not a problem -- even though there are lots of combinations of color and alpha, they are defined very well. Filtering, on the other hand, takes some time to get right :-) Then again, if you got that, you can easily throw in Adam-7 interlacing as well. Doing this all by yourself is indeed a good learning process -- PNGs hold no secrets for *me* anymore!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and guidance to review the libpng.  Yes, this is more for a learning experience.  I like to understand more under-the-hood vs just a mentality of "just use this".  I believe that it helps me when trying to deal with other things, I can relate to similar principles in other work I deal with normally.

Comment: @DRapp: for a real-world sample, see the source code to my [pngdefry](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html) utility for my blunt top-down handling of PNGs -- all work is done in the `process` function. Entirely written with the official specs open on my browser screen.